# Metabox Data not saving

Tags: plugins, php, functions, metabox

My Metabox data doesn't appear once I've saved the page, I tried vardump() on both getextra_mbe_date and getextra_mbe_time which returned null

my code is

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Events CPT
Plugin URI: ****
Description: This Plugins creates an events custom post type with a date and time metabox included.
Version: 0.01
Author: ***
Author URI: ****
License: GPLv2
*/
?>
<?php
function getextra_events_custom_post_type_create() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Events',
    'singular_name'      => 'Event',
    'add_new'            => 'Add New Event',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Event',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Event',
    'new_item'           => 'New Event',
    'all_items'          => 'All Events',
    'view_item'          => 'View Event',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Events',
    'not_found'          => 'No Events found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Eventss found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Events'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'events' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  );
  register_post_type( 'Events', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'getextra_events_custom_post_type_create' );
?>
<?php
//creation of the metabox happens here
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'getextra_mbe_create' );
function getextra_mbe_create() {
    add_meta_box( 'getextra-meta-dt', 'Event Date and Time', 'getextra_mbe_dt_callback', 'Events', 'normal', 'high');
}
//function to display the form fields
function getextra_mbe_dt_callback($post) {
    //get the metadata values if they exist
    $getextra_mbe_date = get_post_meta ($post->ID, '_getextra_mbe_date', true);
    $getextra_mbe_time = get_post_meta ($post->ID, '_getextra_mbe_time', true);
    echo 'Please fill out the event time and date.';
?>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="getextra_mbe_date" value="<?php esc_attr( $getextra_mbe_date); ?>" /></p>
    <p>Time: <input type="text" name="getextra_mbe_time" value="<?php esc_attr( $getextra_mbe_time); ?>" /> </p> 
<?php } 
    //hook to save the meta box data
    add_action ('save_post', 'getextra_mbe_save_dt');

function getextra_mbe_save_dt( $post_id ) {

    //verify the metadata is set
    if (isset( $_POST['getextra_mbe_date'])) {
        //save the metadata
        update_post_meta ($post_id, '_getextra_mbe_date', strip_tags($_POST['getextra_mbe_date']));
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_getextra_mbe_time', strip_tags($_POST['getextra_mbe_time']));
    }

}
 ?>
```

Comment: What else have you tried to debug it? Maybe try echoing out your `$_POST` variables then use `die()` to see what comes out to make sure you even entering your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it saved the custom fields just fine.   The issue is that esc_attr returns a string but does not echo it out.

Try this instead:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" name="getextra_mbe_date" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $getextra_mbe_date); ?>" /></p>
<p>Time: <input type="text" name="getextra_mbe_time" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $getextra_mbe_time); ?>" /> </p>
```